# High memory usage when doing direct transcription with sympy equations

Tags: python, drake

I used `sympy` to derive, via lagrange, the equations of motion of my 3 link robot.  The resultant equation of motion in the form (`theta_dot_dot = f(theta, theta_dot)`) turned out very complicated with A LOT of `cos` and `sin`.  I then [`lambdified`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify) the functions to use with `drake`, replacing all the `sympy.sin` and `sympy.cos` with `drake.sin`, `drake.cos`.

The final function can be evaluated numerically (i.e. given `theta, theta_dot`, find `theta_dot_dot`) somewhat efficiently in the milliseconds range.

I then tried to use direct transcription to do trajectory optimization.  Note I did not use the `DirectTranscription` library, instead manually added the necessary constraints.

The constraints are added roughly as follows:

```
for i in range(NUM_TIME_STEPS-1):
    print("Adding constraints for t = " + str(i))
    tau = mp.NewContinuousVariables(3, "tau_%d" % i)

    next_state = mp.NewContinuousVariables(8, "state_%d" % (i+1))

    for j in range(8):
        mp.AddConstraint(next_state[j] <= (state_over_time[i] + TIME_INTERVAL*derivs(state_over_time[i], tau))[j])
        mp.AddConstraint(next_state[j] >= (state_over_time[i] + TIME_INTERVAL*derivs(state_over_time[i], tau))[j])

    state_over_time[i+1] = next_state
    tau_over_time[i] = tau
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that on each iteration of adding constraints, I observe that my memory usage increases by around 70-100MB.  This means that my number of time steps cannot go more than around 50 before the program crashes due to out of memory.

I'm wondering what I can do to make trajectory optimization work for my robot.  Obviously I can try to simplify (by hand or otherwise) the equations of motions... but is there anything else I can try?  Is it even normal that the constraints are taking up so much memory?  Am I doing something very wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing drake's symbolic through your complex equations.  Making that better is a good goal, but probably you want to avoid it by using the other overload for AddConstraint:

```
AddConstraint(your_method, lb, ub, vars)
```

https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.html?highlight=addconstraint#pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram.AddConstraint

That will use your python code as a function pointer, and should use autodiff instead of symbolic.

Comment: For `AddCost(func, vars)`, func should take a numpy vector of decision variables as the sole argument, and output a double value that is the cost.  The input vector will have the same size as vars.
For `AddConstraint(func, lb, ub, vars)`, func should take the same vector of decision variables as the only input, but the output should be an array/vector (convertible to a numpy vector) that is the same size as lb and ub -- with one element for the value of each constraint at the decision variable values.

Comment: A trivial example can be seen [here](
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/mathematicalprogram_test.py#L466).

[I've also opened a github issue, as I agree we're missing documentation on this.](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12130)